# the name configurationmanager does not exist in the current context

Tags: .net-core, system.configuration

I'm using Visual Studio Community for Mac (.NETCore.App(2.1.0), MacOS 10.14.5) and I'm trying to use the ConfigurationManager class (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8).

But i get the Error Message:

> the name ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context

I already added

```
using System.Configuration
```

to my code and also added the System.Configuration.dll (had to download it manually, because the reference list was completely empty) to the references.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace program
{
  public static class test{
     public static string val(string name){
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package. So please try to execute the following command:

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

**Correction**

Since you are working on Mac, I don't know If you can run the above command. This definitely works inside Visual Studio / Windows. So please follow the instructions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019) for adding a dependency to the package mentioned above.

Comment: don't know why we need to do this as we never needed to before but this fixed worked for me.

Comment: I wasted half an hour with this. Thought that System.Configuration is always there hence never thought of adding it.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2019, I faced the same issue and this is how I resolved it:

Right click on project and go to Manage NuGet Packages.

[image]

Search for System.Configuraion and install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

[image]

Now in your code, configuration manager will be recognized.

[image]